# ¿ Cómo probar proyectos de manera independiente a otros?

Tags: java

Tengo **dos paquetes** en el mismo proyecto con numerosas clases dentro de cada uno. Todas las clases son públicas. **Hay un paquete que presenta fallos** en una de las clases. El otro paquete está sin fallos.

**Quiero probar una clase ejecutable del segundo paquete**, pero no me deja porque primeramente ejecuta el primer paquete, encuentra el fallo de la mencionada clase y **se detiene la ejecución por el error del primer paquete.**

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de **ejecutar el segundo paquete sin ejecutar el primero**. Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, podrías indicar en código lo que tienes. ¿Si ejecutas el paquete2 sin error pero primero se realiza el paquete1 no será porque en el segundo realiza una llamada al primero y salta dicho error? ¿No se puede aislar en otra parte o copiar el código de esa clase ejecutable y probar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar JUnit de java para realizar pruebas unitarias para cada uno de los metodos de cada clase.

Lo que JUnit hace es poder hacer pruebas pequeñas de segmentos de codigo.